# Java Employee Program part 2

Tags: java

How do I get my program to display a random number? This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int empCount = 0;

        System.out.printf("Enter Employee Name: " );
        String name =input.next();
        Employee e1= new Employee(name);
        System.out.printf( "Employee count is " + empCount+ "\n" );

        System.out.println("Employee " + empnumber + e1.getName() + " earned:");
    }
}
```

Here is my code for generating a random number, but I can't seem to get it to return properly.

```
public static int getNumber(){
    Random random = new Random(); 
    int empnumber;
    empnumber = 1000 + random.nextInt( 9999 );
    return empnumber;
}
```

Comment: any feedback on this ?

Answer (score 1):

The variable `empnumber` is not declared globally for the class, it is only in the scope of the `getNumber` method so you won't be able to access it.

Instead use

```
System.out.println("Employee " + Lab3.getNumber() + " earned: " + "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the static method in your main as follows:

```
  int randomNumber = getNumber();
```

Answer (score 0):

add this:

```
 int empCount = Lab3.getNumber();
```